# Reset button does not clear inputs in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this simple `form` in my `App` form. I learned that a `button` with `type="reset"` clears the inputs, but it isn't working here with React. Am I missing something?

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Name"
        name="name"
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
      <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: You have controlled input. Reset won't work. Either use uncontrolled input or use `setState('')` to reset the value

Comment: IMO, use an object to maintain the initial state of the form and on RESET, update the state using initial object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must reset the state name with an empty string when the reset button is clicked.

```
export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const onClickReset = () => setName('');
  
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Name"
        name="name"
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" onClick={onClickReset}>Reset</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Use an object to maintain the initial state of the form and on RESET, update the state using the initial object.

Also, use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the default action of the reset button.

```js
const {useState} = React;


 function App() {
   const initState = {
     name:''
   };
  const [name, setName] = useState(initState.name);
  const onReset = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(initState.name);
  }
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Name"
        name="name"
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" onClick={e=>onReset(e)}>Reset</button>
    </form>
  );
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Name"
        name="name"
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" onClick={() => setName('')}>Reset</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your input is now controlled by a state, if you want to clear the form by type='reset' try removing the value and onChange attributes in your input. but if you want to clear the state you can create a function that will handle this. here's a sample function for your reference.

```
function handleClear() {
   setName('')
}

<button type="button" onClick={handleClear}>Reset</button>
```